# Always display two digits after decimal separator navision

Tags: report, decimal, navision

I'm using Microsoft Navision 2009. I'm creating report that includes several number with decimal separator (double/float number in C#).

I'm stuck at the point where I want to display every number with two digits after decimal point.

Ex:

if number is 100, I want to display 100.00
if number is 100.5, I want to display 100.50
if number is 100.55, I want to display 100.55
if number is 100.505; i want to display either 100.51 or 100.50

Thank you in advance;

Language that I'm using is C/AL

Comment: What type is the field in nav? Text? Decimal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't be lazy. Read essential manuals. `Format` function is your best friend in Nav.

`strsubstno(text01,format(100.10,0,'<Precision,2:2><Standard Format,0>'))`
Third argument of Format is actually the format of result text. `<Precision,2:3>` means that if first argument is decimal it will have from 2 to 3 (minimum 2 and maximum 3) digits in decimal part. `<Standard Format,0>` means that the rest of format will be standard.

More [here!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd301059.aspx)